# Code doesn't loop as expected - I get same results for each URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I try to scrape an e-commerce site to find out which of the items, from each category, are on sale. The code runs through 30 pages with 30 products on each page.
The below code gives me the same answer for each category, 76, but this is incorrect. I'm not entirely sure why it keeps adding 2 for each time it loops through a page, and how to fix this. 
I feel like it's a small page, but I can't seem to identify the culprit.

The products on sale can be identified by the `.price-standard` class.

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = {
    "Charms": "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element",
    "Bracelets": "https://us.pandora.net/en/bracelets/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element",
    "Rings": "https://us.pandora.net/en/rings/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element",
    "Necklaces": "https://us.pandora.net/en/necklaces/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element",
    "Earrings": "https://us.pandora.net/en/earrings/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
}

#checks each item for whether it's on sale - which is classed by .price-standard
def fetch_items(link,page):
    Total_items = 0 
    while page<=900:
        #print("current page no: ",page)
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        list_total = soup.select('.grid-tile .price-standard') #this is where the information can be found  
        Total_items += len(list_total)
        #print(Total_items)
        page+=30
    return Total_items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    page = 0
    total_items = fetch_items(url,page)

    #I try to make it print the Total for each category (charms, bracelets, rings, necklaces, earrings)    
    for category, url in urls.items():
        print("Total {}: {}".format(category, total_items))
```

EDIT:
It works, guys!
This is the result.

```
Total Charms: 295
Total Bracelets: 47
Total Rings: 174
Total Necklaces: 132
Total Earrings: 76
```

Comment: This code, as posted, should not work at all (`url` is not defined when you call `fetch_items(url, page)`). Anyway, `fetch_items(url, page)` should be inside the loop.

Comment: Check your results from `get`, and check what's in `list_total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put `total_items = fetch_items(url,page)` inside loop.

This code fetchs it only once and it seems that `url` variable is defined somewhere else.